# Docker cannot write to assets folder as web server process in Yii/PHP application locally OS X

Tags: php, macos, yii, docker

appreciate if you could help me.

I'm running docker VM in a MAC OS X and seems okay until i reach a permissions error when my app is trying to write files in the assets folder in the server:

```
CAssetManager.basePath "/var/www/html/assets" is invalid. Please make sure the directory exists and is writable by the Web server process.
```

I ran `ls -l` in the docker container shell ($ docker exec container) and saw that my folder permissions are set to 
`drwxrwxrwx 1000 staff assets`. Following that, i tried to set it to www-data as i though it might work , so  i ran `usermod -u 1000 www-data`. Now folder becomes: `drwxrwxrwx www-data staff assets` but the error persists.

In the shell, I also tried to run `chmod` and `chown` commands but i get these errors:

`chown: changing ownership of 'assets': Read-only file system`

`chmod: changing ownership of 'assets': Read-only file system`

How can i enable my directory to be writable by the web server process in docker?

**UPDATE:**

`$ docker ps` returns

[image]

`$ docker info## Heading ##` returns

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
`$ docker inspect` returns
http://pastebin.com/wM3tT51v

Comment: Can you post your docker run command so we can see how you are starting the container?

Comment: hi these are my containers. i start my containers on $ eb local run using the AWS Elasticbeanstalk cli.

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                         NAMES
aa65773c3824        nginx:latest         "nginx -g 'daemon off"   5 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp   elasticbeanstalk_nginxproxy_1
bfef894e9665        merrymaker/php:fpm   "php-fpm"                6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        9000/tcp                      elasticbeanstalk_phpapp_1

Comment: Can you add those to your question, vs in the comment it is hard to read in the comments. Do you have any volumes?

Comment: @KenCochrane, no problem. thanks for participating, i have included snapshots in the question for more context.

Comment: Thanks, can you run `docker inspect` for the container with the issue, and show the mounts section, so we can see if there are any volumes

Comment: @KenCochrane hey buddy, resolved the issue. It was due to aws dockerfile  (Dockerrun.aws.json) that set container permissions to read-only. Appreciate your time and response, have a good day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the docker inspect output

```
        "Mounts": [
        {
            "Source": "/Users/joelkoh/Sites/merrymaker/php-app",
            "Destination": "/var/www/html",
            "Mode": "ro",
            "RW": false,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
```

It looks like your directory is read only, I'm not familiar with elastic beanstalk, but you will need to change that volume so it isn't read only.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using http://docker-sync.io for mounting shares. Since it is not mounting, but syncing, it solved the user permission-problems by mapping your desired uid/guid to the container https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/blob/master/example/docker-sync.yml#L47

This way you have a very performant share, but also, having a proper user mapping to never care about permission issues in the container ( for host-mounted folders )